# How to show apt-get install suggestions in command line?

Tags: command-line, apt, bash

I have VPS minimum Ubuntu installed and I would like it to show (i.e.):

```
The program add-apt-repository is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: 

apt-get install python-software-properties
```

Currently it only shows

```
add-apt-repository: command not found
```

What package controls command like (bash) suggestions for apt-get commands?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The package responsible for verbose and more helpful "command not found" messages is [`command-not-found`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/command-not-found/).

Install it by running

```
sudo apt-get install command-not-found
```

Comment: Thanks. That is - it worked. To others: don't forget to reset bash terminal (I do it manually exit and connect, I don't know other method)